# Where are official Ubuntu PGP keys listed?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I've been trying to Google this, but so far nothing. Could anything point me to where Ubuntu lists their official PGP keys for packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as long as you trust this server you will get them 
here with a nice search:

http://keyserver.ubuntu.com